# Detecting basic shapes using Open CV

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm looking at a way to detect basic shapes from an image using open CV in Python.

This is the code that I have used to detect the basic images, which works:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import webbrowser

img = cv2.imread('test3.png')
gray = cv2.imread('test3.png',0)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,1)

contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,1,2)

for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True), True)
    print len(approx)
    if len(approx)==5:
    print "It's a pentagon = mortgages."
    webbrowser.open('http://www.google.co.uk')
    #cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,255,-1)
elif len(approx)==3:
    print "triangle"
    cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,255,0),-1)
elif len(approx)==4:
    print "square"
    cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,0,255),-1)
elif len(approx) == 9:
    print "half-circle"
    cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(255,255,0),-1)
elif len(approx) > 15:
    print "circle"
    cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,255,255),-1)

#cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, it outputs the result twice. Any advice or example to correct it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by *"outputs the result twice"*? Please review the indentation in your code, it's important in Python.

Comment: if you have something like a line-triangle (so not an object, but a contour) with different color than the background, you will end up finding two contours, one in the inside and one on the outside of those lines. As KeillRandor suggests you could use parameters to find only the outer contour, but in that scenario you might miss other shapes within that contour (if for example a circle within a square is allowed). Maybe you can just filter out doubled shapes, if you have knowledge about line size. Or you can try to compute the "inner" contours in further steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve only the outter contours of the object, add the proper flag to `cv2.findContours`:

```
contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,2)
```

otherwise it can return more than one contour per shape, hence the repeated result in the `for` loop.

Hope that it helps.